# How should I use headers on my Pi Pico?

Tags: pi-pico

I bought a couple of Pi Pico.

The Pico is very wide and leaves little space on a breadboard -- I'd like to add headers on my Pi Pico, but I am not sure about the best way to arrange this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used various Arduino Nano, ProMini etc in projects over the years.
Mostly I have installed headers so I could prototype.

The Pi Pico is quite wide so takes up most of the space on a breadboard.

I used double-sided headers on one for prototyping.
This gives you access to the pins on the Pico in addition to the breadboard.

These are a little shorter (1mm) than usual, but still OK for a du-pont cable.

[image: Pico double0-sided header]

If you try this be sparing with the solder so it doesn't flow up the pins.

Answer (score 6):

Headers or no headers depend on the usage. If you are embedding the Pico in a project you may not need or want headers. If you plan to prototype using a breadboard, you can use [stacking headers](https://thepihut.com/products/stacking-header-set-for-raspberry-pi-pico).

[image: Tall stacking headers]

They will allow you to use the breadboard and the female headers. One advantage is these don't require female Dupont cables.

If you need even more space, you can use a pair of breadboards (with the power rails removed and insert one row of the Pico's pins into each breadboard. It is similar to what is shown below with an [ESP32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ESP32).

[image: Spanning two breadboards]

I just saw a [youtube video](https://youtu.be/VX5NjZKHCEA?t=549) that uses a friction fit to connect the Pico to male header pins inserted into a breadboard - no soldering required. Might make a good option if you only need to quickly prototype a circuit and then embed the board into your project, or as a quick hack.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit dependent on what you plan on doing with the Pico. Is it going to be embedded in a project or do you plan on keeping this Pico as a development board and putting other Picos into projects once they're prototyped?

If it's being embedded then you may want to avoid putting headers on it as they may make the Pico too large to fit and long headers are tedious to de-solder without the proper equipment. That being said, without headers it can be tricky to prototype using that same board.

If it's not being embedded then headers are definitely recommended for ease of use. If the amount of space taken up on the breadboard is a significant impedance then you have a couple of options.

First, as [Milliways mentioned](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/120678/should-i-use-headers-on-my-pi-pico/120679#120679), you can use extra long headers to effectively make the pins double-sided, so you can plug wires directly to the pins as well as the breadboard.

Secondly, should you require more room at the cost of tidiness, you can use a jumper cable to break the pin out farther down the board to give yourself more space.

Thirdly, if space on the board is getting critical, you can attach the Pico to the breadboard via some ribbon cables in order to get both rows of pins against the centre. This would of course require you making a custom wire harness as I doubt there are any ready-made cables that would fit perfectly, but it should be fairly straightforward with a couple strips of female-to-male Dupont cable strips.